# Vertical Split in spacemacs like emacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to open two windows in spacemacs side by side like I used to do in vanilla emacs with the following line in my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '2-windows-vertical-to-horizontal)
```

and from the terminal

```
emacs file1 file2
```

The spacemacs library was suggested to me, and I think I dig it but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to replicate this functionality in the .spacemacs file

what do I need to add and where does it need to go so that I can have my preferred configuration back?

Comment: Spacemacs is a library used by Emacs.  It is not a special stand-alone animal.  Please edit your question and post the entire code for `2-windows-vertical-to-horizontal`.

Comment: Just using M-x 3 M-m 2 C-x C-f /filename for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '2-windows-vertical-to-horizontal)`in 
`dotspacemacs/user-config` in your `.spacemacs` file.it will work as you expect

Comment: Thats what i found. Thanks for following up.